# Using itextsharp xmlworker to convert html to pdf and write text vertically

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, itext, xmlworker

Is there possible to achieve writing text direction bottom-up in xmlworker? I would like to use it in table. 
My code is

```
     <table border=1>
     <tr>
     <td style="padding-right:18px">
          <p style="writing-mode:sideways-lr;text-align:center">First</p</td>
     <td style="padding-right:18px">
          <p style="writing-mode:sideways-lr;text-align:center">Second</p></td></tr>
     <tr><td><p style="text-align:center">1</p>  </td>
         <td><p style="text-align:center">2</p></td> 
     </tr>
        </table>
```

But it it doesn't work after conversion from html to pdf. Text FIRST and SECOND are not in direction bottom-to-up.

Comment: You need to write custom code to do this. If you add a `HTML`sample of what you expect, someone _might_ be able to help...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This was a pretty interesting problem, so +1 to the question.

The first step was to lookup whether or not iTextSharp XML Worker supports the `HTML` `td` tag. The mappings can be found in the source in [iTextSharp.tool.xml.html.Tags](https://github.com/itext/itextsharp/blob/develop/src/extras/itextsharp.xmlworker/iTextSharp/tool/xml/html/Tags.cs). There you find `td` is mapped to [iTextSharp.tool.xml.html.table.TableData](https://github.com/itext/itextsharp/blob/develop/src/extras/itextsharp.xmlworker/iTextSharp/tool/xml/html/table/TableData.cs), which makes the job of implementing a custom tag processor a little easier. I.e. all we need to do inherit from the class and override `End()`:

```
public class TableDataProcessor : TableData
{
    /*
     * a **very** simple implementation of the CSS writing-mode property:
     * https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/writing-mode
     */
    bool HasWritingMode(IDictionary<string, string> attributeMap)
    {
        bool hasStyle = attributeMap.ContainsKey("style");
        return hasStyle
                && attributeMap["style"].Split(new char[] { ';' })
                .Where(x => x.StartsWith("writing-mode:"))
                .Count() > 0
            ? true : false;
    }

    public override IList<IElement> End(
        IWorkerContext ctx,
        Tag tag,
        IList<IElement> currentContent)
    {
        var cells = base.End(ctx, tag, currentContent);
        var attributeMap = tag.Attributes;
        if (HasWritingMode(attributeMap))
        {
            var pdfPCell = (PdfPCell) cells[0];
            // **always** 'sideways-lr'
            pdfPCell.Rotation = 90;
        }
        return cells;
    }
}
```

As noted in the inline comments, this is a **very** simple implementation for your specific needs. You'll need to add extra logic to support any other [**writing-mode** `CSS` property value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/writing-mode), and include any sanity checks.

## UPDATE

Based on the comment left by [@Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4183575/daniel), it's not clear how to add custom `CSS` when converting the `HTML` to `PDF`. First the updated HTML:

```
string XHTML = @"
<h1>Table with Vertical Text</h1>
<table><tr>
<td style='writing-mode:sideways-lr;text-align:center;width:40px;'>First</td>
<td style='writing-mode:sideways-lr;text-align:center;width:40px;'>Second</td></tr>
<tr><td style='text-align:center'>1</td>
<td style='text-align:center'>2</td></tr></table>

<h1>Table <u>without</u> Vertical Text</h1>
<table width='50%'>
<tr><td class='light-yellow'>0</td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td></tr>
<tr><td class='light-yellow'>2</td></tr>
<tr><td>3</td></tr>
</table>";
```

Then a small snippet of custom CSS:

```
string CSS = @"
    body {font-size: 12px;}
    table {border-collapse:collapse; margin:8px;}
    .light-yellow {background-color:#ffff99;}
    td {border:1px solid #ccc;padding:4px;}
";
```

The slightly difficult part is the extra setup - you can't use the simple out of the box `XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml()` commonly seen here at SO. Here's a simple helper method that should get you started:

```
public void ConvertHtmlToPdf(string xHtml, string css)
{
    using (var stream = new FileStream(OUTPUT_FILE, FileMode.Create))
    {
        using (var document = new Document())
        {
            var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, stream);
            document.Open();

            // instantiate custom tag processor and add to `HtmlPipelineContext`.
            var tagProcessorFactory = Tags.GetHtmlTagProcessorFactory();
            tagProcessorFactory.AddProcessor(
                new TableDataProcessor(), 
                new string[] { HTML.Tag.TD }
            );
            var htmlPipelineContext = new HtmlPipelineContext(null);
            htmlPipelineContext.SetTagFactory(tagProcessorFactory);

            var pdfWriterPipeline = new PdfWriterPipeline(document, writer);
            var htmlPipeline = new HtmlPipeline(htmlPipelineContext, pdfWriterPipeline);

            // get an ICssResolver and add the custom CSS
            var cssResolver = XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().GetDefaultCssResolver(true);
            cssResolver.AddCss(css, "utf-8", true);
            var cssResolverPipeline = new CssResolverPipeline(
                cssResolver, htmlPipeline
            );

            var worker = new XMLWorker(cssResolverPipeline, true);
            var parser = new XMLParser(worker);
            using (var stringReader = new StringReader(xHtml))
            {
                parser.Parse(stringReader);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Instead of rehashing an explanation of the example code above, [see the documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20170708105650/http://demo.itextsupport.com/xmlworker/itextdoc/flatsite.html) (iText removed documentation, linked to Wayback Machine) to get a better idea of why you need to setup the parser that way.

Also note:

1. XML Worker **does not** support all CSS2/CSS3 properties, so you *may* need to experiment with what works or doesn't work with regards to how close you want the PDF to look to the HTML displayed in the browser.
2. The `HTML` snippet removed the `p` tag, since the style can be applied directly to the `td` tag.
3. The inline `width` property. If omitted the columns will be variable widths that match if the text had been rendered horizontally.

Tested with iTextSharp and XML Worker versions 5.5.9 Here's the **updated** result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's very helpful. In my case html file is big. There is lot of tables but only two tables needs  vertical text  I wonder how to implement into your code rest of my own css.  I did this before: `using (var myCss = new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(example_css)))
                        {
                            using (var msHtml = new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(example_html)))
                            {              iTextSharp.tool.xml.XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, doc, msHtml, myCss );
     }
     }
`

Comment: @Daniel - updated the answer to include a helper method that allows you to pass a `HTML` string and a `CSS` string.

Comment: @kuujinbo I am trying your method but this is undefined  
"new TableDataProcessor() " also documentation link not working

Comment: @kuujinbo Last update almost 2 years ago.
If you could update again that would be great

Comment: @Selman - updated hyperlinks. `TableDataProcessor` **is** part of the code example, so you need to include it in whatever you're doing. With that said, I haven't used iText in a **long** time, but I do know they are recommending using version 7.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void addHtmlToPdf(Document document, PdfWriter writer, String html) {
    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
    PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
    ElementList list = XMLWorkerHelper.ParseToElementList(html, null);
    foreach(IElement element in list) {
        cell.AddElement(element);
    }
    table.AddCell(cell);
    document.Add(table);
}
```

Alternative with utf8:

```
public void addHtmlToPdf_Utf8(Document document, PdfWriter writer, String html) 
{
    XMLWorkerHelper xml = XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance();
    xml.ParseXHtml(writer, document, stringToStream(html), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
}
public Stream stringToStream(string txt) {
    var stream = new MemoryStream();
    var w = new StreamWriter(stream);
    w.Write(txt);
    w.Flush();
    stream.Position = 0;
    return stream;
}
```