# Inline CSS for hr not applied while converting html to pdf using iText library

Tags: android, html, itext, xmlworker

I am using Itext library for android for converting html to pdf which is working fine but at certain things it is not parsing properly. I want to create a dotted line separator of red color but it is always gives me a solid line separator with dark gray color.

My html tag is

```
<hr noshade style="border: 0; width:100%;border-bottom-width: 1px; border-bottom-style: dotted; border-bottom-color: red">
```

My conversion code

```
        Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4);

        //this sets the margin to the created pdf
        document.setMargins(35, 35, 150, 100);

        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document,
                new FileOutputStream(fileWithinMyDir));
        if (isPrescription) {
            HeaderFooterPageEvent event = new HeaderFooterPageEvent();
            writer.setPageEvent(event);
        } else {
            CertificateFooterPageEvent event = new CertificateFooterPageEvent();
            writer.setPageEvent(event);
        }
        document.open();
        HtmlPipelineContext htmlContext = new HtmlPipelineContext(null);
        htmlContext.setTagFactory(Tags.getHtmlTagProcessorFactory());
        htmlContext.setImageProvider(new AbstractImageProvider() {
            public String getImageRootPath() {

                Uri uri = Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/");

                return uri.toString();
            }
        });


        CSSResolver cssResolver =
                XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().getDefaultCssResolver(false);

        // Pipelines
        PdfWriterPipeline pdf = new PdfWriterPipeline(document, writer);
        HtmlPipeline html = new HtmlPipeline(htmlContext, pdf);
        CssResolverPipeline css = new CssResolverPipeline(cssResolver, html);

        XMLWorker worker = new XMLWorker(css, true);

        XMLParser p = new XMLParser(worker);
        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(htmlString.getBytes());
        XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(writer, document, is);
        p.parse(is);

        document.close();
```

Comment: Not used iText so I can only offer a suggestion. Try adding `background-color: transparent;` to the `hr`s styles and remove `noshade`: `<hr style="border: 0; width:100%; border-bottom: 1px; dotted red; background-color: transparent;" />`.

Comment: @HiddenHobbes still the same, the problem is with the library and i am searching for a work around.

Answer (score 6):

I'm a .NET developer, so the code is in C#. But you should be able to easily translate the following.

iText is a PDF-first library, and `[X]HTML` parsing is quite complex so it's not full featured in that regard. Whenever parsing `[X]HTML` and things aren't going the way you expect for specific tags, the basic steps you should follow are:

1. Verify `XML Worker` supports the tag: [Tags class](https://github.com/itext/itextpdf/blob/develop/xmlworker/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/tool/xml/html/Tags.java).
2. If the tag *is* supported, which in this case is true, take a look at the default implementation. Here it's handled by the [the HorizontalRule class](https://github.com/itext/itextpdf/blob/develop/xmlworker/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/tool/xml/html/HorizontalRule.java). However, we see there's no support for your use case, so one way to go is use that code as a blueprint. (follows below) You can also inherit from the specific tag class and override the End() method [as done here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36180131#36214013). Either way, all you're doing is implementing a custom tag processor.
3. If the tag is **not** supported, you need to roll your own custom tag processor by inheriting from [AbstractTagProcessor](https://github.com/itext/itextpdf/blob/develop/xmlworker/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/tool/xml/html/AbstractTagProcessor.java).

Anyway, here's a simple example to get you started. First, the custom tag processor:

```
public class CustomHorizontalRule : AbstractTagProcessor
{
    public override IList<IElement> Start(IWorkerContext ctx, Tag tag)
    {
        IList<IElement> result;
        LineSeparator lineSeparator;
        var cssUtil = CssUtils.GetInstance();

        try
        {
            IList<IElement> list = new List<IElement>();
            HtmlPipelineContext htmlPipelineContext = this.GetHtmlPipelineContext(ctx);

            Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();
            IDictionary<string, string> css = tag.CSS;
            float baseValue = 12f;
            if (css.ContainsKey("font-size"))
            {
                baseValue = cssUtil.ParsePxInCmMmPcToPt(css["font-size"]);
            }
            string text;
            css.TryGetValue("margin-top", out text);
            if (text == null) text = "0.5em";

            string text2;
            css.TryGetValue("margin-bottom", out text2);
            if (text2 == null) text2 = "0.5em";

            string border;
            css.TryGetValue(CSS.Property.BORDER_BOTTOM_STYLE, out border);
            lineSeparator = border != null && border == "dotted"
                ? new DottedLineSeparator()
                : new LineSeparator();

            var element = (LineSeparator)this.GetCssAppliers().Apply(
                lineSeparator, tag, htmlPipelineContext
            );

            string color;
            css.TryGetValue(CSS.Property.BORDER_BOTTOM_COLOR, out color);
            if (color != null)
            {
                // WebColors deprecated, but docs don't state replacement
                element.LineColor = WebColors.GetRGBColor(color);
            }

            paragraph.SpacingBefore += cssUtil.ParseValueToPt(text, baseValue);
            paragraph.SpacingAfter += cssUtil.ParseValueToPt(text2, baseValue);
            paragraph.Leading = 0f;
            paragraph.Add(element);
            list.Add(paragraph);
            result = list;
        }
        catch (NoCustomContextException cause)
        {
            throw new RuntimeWorkerException(
                LocaleMessages.GetInstance().GetMessage("customcontext.404"),
                cause
            );
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Most of the code is taken directly from the existing source, with the exception of the checks for `CSS.Property.BORDER_BOTTOM_STYLE` and `CSS.Property.BORDER_BOTTOM_COLOR` to set border style and color if they're inlined in the `<hr>` `style` attribute.

Then you add the custom tag processor above to the XML Worker `TagProcessorFactory`:

```
using (var stream = new FileStream(OUTPUT_FILE, FileMode.Create))
{
    using (var document = new Document())
    {
        var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, stream);
        document.Open();

        var tagProcessorFactory = Tags.GetHtmlTagProcessorFactory();
        // custom tag processor above
        tagProcessorFactory.AddProcessor(
            new CustomHorizontalRule(),
            new string[] { HTML.Tag.HR }
        );
        var htmlPipelineContext = new HtmlPipelineContext(null);
        htmlPipelineContext.SetTagFactory(tagProcessorFactory);

        var pdfWriterPipeline = new PdfWriterPipeline(document, writer);
        var htmlPipeline = new HtmlPipeline(htmlPipelineContext, pdfWriterPipeline);
        var cssResolver = XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().GetDefaultCssResolver(true);
        var cssResolverPipeline = new CssResolverPipeline(
            cssResolver, htmlPipeline
        );

        var worker = new XMLWorker(cssResolverPipeline, true);
        var parser = new XMLParser(worker);
        var xHtml = "<hr style='border:1px dotted red' />";
        using (var stringReader = new StringReader(xHtml))
        {
            parser.Parse(stringReader);
        }
    }
}
```

One thing to note is that even though we're using the shorthand `border` inline style, iText's CSS parser appears to set **all** the styles internally. I.e., you can use any of the four longhand styles to check - I just happened to use `CSS.Property.BORDER_BOTTOM_STYLE` and `CSS.Property.BORDER_BOTTOM_COLOR`.

The resulting PDF:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could use a div without any or with any content you want instead of an hr and give border style to that div, I am sure it will work in your case.